# I want to add Json Array type request body into my mongoose database as a single documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is the order model

```
const mongoose=require('mongoose');
const items = require('../models/item_model');

const orderSchema=mongoose.Schema({
    
    item_id: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        ref: 'Item',
        require: true
    },
    handicraftmen_id  : {type: String ,require: true},
    customer_id : {type: String ,require: true},
    quantity : {type : Number,default: 1},
    status : {type : Number,default:1},
    amount:{type:Number,require:true}, 
    createDate :{type: String, require:true},

},{timestamps: true}); 
 
module.exports = mongoose.model('Order',orderSchema);
```

and my request body is kind of like an array below.

```
[
    {
        "item_id": "62fa132d8c29dac0417afd36",
        "handicraftmen_id":"62fa132d8c29dac0417afd89",
        "cutomer_id":"62fa132d8c29dac0417agf45",
        "qty": "4",
        "amount":"2000"
    },
    {
        "item_id": "62fa132d8c29dac0417afd36",
        "handicraftmen_id":"62fa132d8c29dac0417afd89",
        "cutomer_id":"62fa132d8c29dac0417agf45",
        "qty": "1",
        "amount":"500"
    },
    {
        "item_id": "62fa132d8c29dac0417afd36",
        "handicraftmen_id":"62fa132d8c29dac0417afd89",
        "cutomer_id":"62fa132d8c29dac0417agf45",
        "qty": "3",
        "amount":"1500"
    }
]
```

I want to add the above request body one by one into the database.

how should I add this using node and mongoose queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the code below does something similar. Refer to the link https://www.tutorialkart.com/nodejs/mongoose/insert-multiple-documents-to-mongodb/

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
// make a connection
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/tutorialkart');
 
// get reference to database
var db = mongoose.connection;
 
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
 
db.once('open', function() {
  console.log("Connection Successful!");
     
  // define Schema
  var BookSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    price: Number,
    quantity: Number
  });
 
  // compile schema to model
  var Book = mongoose.model('Book', BookSchema, 'bookstore');
 
  // documents array
  var books = [
    { name: 'Mongoose Tutorial', price: 10, quantity: 25 },
    { name: 'NodeJS tutorial', price: 15, quantity: 5 },
    { name: 'MongoDB Tutorial', price: 20, quantity: 2 }
  ];
 
  // save multiple documents to the collection referenced by Book Model
  Book.collection.insert(books, function (err, docs) {
    if (err) { 
      return console.error(err);
    } else {
      console.log("Multiple documents inserted to Collection");
    }
  });
});
```